# Reading and wiriting to socket in SSL mode (lNet)

Tags: ssl, pascal, lazarus, freepascal

I use lNet component. I have cert and pkey.
I create server for multi clients connections. Without SSL everything is OK. On OnReceive function I receive aSocket:

```
procedure TFormMain.LTCPComponentReceive(aSocket: TLSocket);
var
  s: string;
begin
  if aSocket.GetMessage(s) > 0 then begin
    //save socket in some array or map - SomeArray[I]:=aSocket;
```

after this I can identify socket, read and write into socket in some array f.ex

```
TLTCPComponent.SendMessage(SomeArray[I], Message);
```

but when I switch on SSL Mode this doesnt work :( Can you tell me how should I create SSL connction, read and write data in SSL connection mode for few clients sockets?

Generaly now it looks like this:

- client connets to server
- server save aSocket into array
- server can write into aSockets in array

it works without SSL, with SSL doesnt :(

I look into demos but there is example with sending to all connected clients but I would like to identify clients and read, send data for specify one.

I realy need an example and help :(

thx!